How to explain to people that I have speaking problems?
I have a mild form of aphasia (that affects speech but not written communication). Speaking takes me a lot of effort and requires concentration, and it's very difficult to speak and think about something non-trivial at the same time (imagine that you have to solve a math task and speak to someone about something unrelated at the same time).
So, I use written communication whenever possible. However, many people insist to call me instead.
Usually, I'm just doing my best to hide it, but this often doesn't work well as many people assume that lack in fluency in speech means stupidity.
Also, I suspect that some people thought that I just make the problems up for attention seeking, and the reaction that I got varied from ignoring to open hostility.
So, usually I just hide it.
I tried to explain it to the HRs before the job interview (see the first paragraph for an example of such explanation) and asked for communication in written (as stated by ADA), but one interviewer out of 3 ignored it completely and another ignored it partially.
How to explain them these problems so that they really understand, and what to do if they ignore it?

What have you tried in the past when dealing with this? What was perceived as untactful? Or what are planning on telling these people, and what part of it are you worried will be untactful? Are you lying about the reason or disclosing the aphasia honestly?

@Tinkeringbell do you really need to know what I've been done to answer the question how (you think) this should be done?

Answering what she thinks your conversation should be would be off topic. Please edit your question to include what you have tried in the past and to make it not opinion-based

@BentleyCarpenter well, I don't know much about the unwritten rules here. What makes it off topic? In any case, an answer on a topic of inter-personal relations or psychology would be opinion-based. We're not talking about mathematics where everything can be proven objectively.

Please read the guide in the help center: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask , https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

@BentleyCarpenter well, if you insist. But that information won't give you nothing in the context of this particular question.

This site is about to be disregarded anyway (it's entering the beta phase). You should ask your question somewhere else--I am not trying to be hurtful, but it is the truth. The admin literally doesn't want anyone to ask questions here. Have you seen the high rate of question closure by this admin?

@NapoleonBonaparte ah I see. Thanks.

@Tinkeringbell this question seems ok to me, the final question is quite objective. I'm sad I have to agree with Napoleon Bonaparte above here

@Tinkeringbell rejecting reopening of the question and not explaining why doesn't help at all.
